# Angular + Firebase + Cordova google auth

Tags: android, angular, firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication

I have a ready-made web application on Angular 10 + Firebase with Google Account authorization.

But when I made android app with cordova

```
angularFireAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)
```

It didn't work, failing with:

> Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

The same to `angularFireAuth.signInWithRedirect(provider)`.

What should I use to make google auth in angular + cordova + firebase android app?

I've read https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova but it didn't help -- I can't install all plugins (errors appear) , and all I've read about cordova didn't help because I have main functionality in my Angular AuthService , where I'm using AngularFireAuth.

This is my first project with cordova and angularfire, so I'm stuck and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) to load the Cordova app into the Webview using `http://` instead of `file://`.

Or use native mobile Firebase SDK e.g. [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) and use [`authenticateUserWithGoogle()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#authenticateuserwithgoogle).